# Too many Request (429) error when using Flutter Http library to send a Post request

Tags: flutter, api, http, dart, http-status-code-429

The code below returns a 429 status code. What's the issue

```
const Map<String, String> _headers =  {
'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
'Authorization': 'Bearer 9|YNYTWEW89LI1NOM1lf7TxcZZSP',
};
Uri url = Uri.parse('http://7981.00/postdata/');
Map<String, dynamic> data = {};
data['first'] = 'data1';
data['dataList'] = List<Map<String, dynamic>> listData
String _body = jsonEncode(orderTable);
http.Response response = await http.post(url, headers: _headers, body: _body);
print(response.statuscode);
```

Comment: How do you call this api? It seems not depend on http library.

Comment: I use the http.post

Comment: Please share more details if you call this method in build function or StatefulWidget or not.

Comment: I call this method in an onpressed property

Comment: Could you share onpress function?

Comment: ` TextButton( `
          onPressed: (){
            length != 0 ?
            confirmPost()
            : print('false'); } `

Comment: got answer? i go the same error when posting Paypal response to my db in flutter.